# Calculate edits in QuickTime Movie File with Edit List Atom

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, quicktime

In a **Linux** environment, is there a way to calculate any edits in a QuickTime Movie File track? Specifically, I need duration and start time of edits in relation to the movie.

I have been parsing the raw mov file to look at the **Edit List Atom** ( i.e. **'elst'** ) to get the track duration and media time but, even after the adjustments for time scale units the start time always seems off.

For example, I have a single track video which has been edited to have first and last 6 seconds of the video removed. However, when I look at the 'elst' atom of that file the track duration is the length of the new file but, the media time does not match what I would have expected (i.e. something equivalent to 6 seconds).

I have tried looking into tools like FFmpeg but have had little success.